# Oracle rownum = 1 to select topmost row from the set fails

Tags: oracle, rownum, top-n

I need to select from two tables,

RATING_TABLE

```
  RATING_TYPE       RATING_PRIORITY
  TITAN             1
  PLATINUM(+)       1  
  PLATINUM          2
  DIAMOND(+)        3
  DIAMOND           3  
  GOLD              4
  SILVER            4
```

RATING_STORAGE

```
RATING           AMOUNT  
SILVER           200
GOLD             510
DIAMOND          850
PLATINUM(+)      980
TITAN            5000
```

I want to select the rating from **RATING_STORAGE** table based on RATING_PRIORITY from **RATING_TABLE**. 
I want to select **one row** with lowest rating priority. If two rating priority are eqaul I want to choose the one with the lowest amount.
So I used the query,

```
select s.rating,s.amount 
from RATING_TABLE r, RATING_STORAGE s 
where        r.rating_type= s.rating_type 
and rownum=1 
order by  r.rating_priority asc , s.amount asc ;
```

I am getting correct output when sorting the result but **rownum=1** fails to give the topmost row.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select after sorting is done, in your case:

```
     select *
  from (select s.rating
              ,s.amount
          from rating_table   r
              ,rating_storage s
         where r.rating_type = s.rating_type
           and rownum = 1
         order by r.rating_priority asc
                 ,s.amount          asc)
 where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using this query in stored procedure where I have to store the selected values with INTO clause which is making errors